# Liferay export structure

Tags: liferay

I'm working in LifeRay 6.1 CE GA 2.

I want to save/export the structure of my portal:

- 1 Organization
- 4 Sites
- 3 Roles
- 3 Groups

I need copy the **structure** ( Orgs, sites, groups and roles ), but not users, content, pages...

Which is the best way to achieve it?

**LAR's** only export pages & portlet configs...

On **Control Panel >Server > Scripts**, this is like to do it programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

Best way for export/import structure is to do through Control Panel -> Users and Organization -> Export/Import.

Select Permissions while export/import and you will get Roles as well.

For UserGroups you have do another LAR file export/import.

For sites there is no export/import.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an export for the entire portal structures, you have to export every site.
You cannot export Roles.

Too bad news?